# SQL Server sp_BlitzCache - Many Plans for One Query

Tags: sp-blitz, sp-blitzcache

I'm in need of a bit of assistance.

I ran sp_Blitz on one of my SQL Servers and one of the results it returned is "1531 plans are present for a single query in the plan cache - meaning we probably have parameterization issues.".

I followed [the link](https://BrentOzar.com/go/parameterization) in the result.

I then ran sp_BlitzCache @ExpertMode = 1 to find queries with multiple plans but the #Plans and #Distinct Plans columns both return the value 1 for all rows.

How do I proceed to isolate the single query that has multiple plans?

**Environment:
SQL 2012 SP3 CU8**

*sp_BlitzCache version 5.7*

Comment: Did you get 1531+ results for `sp_BlitzCache @ExpertMode = 1` each with a 1 in the `#Plans` and `#DistinctPlans` column?

Comment: Nope - sp_BlitzCache returned 10 rows 1 each with a 1 in the #Plans and #DistinctPlans column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So close! Problem is you didn't actually [read the page you linked to](https://brentozar.com/go/parameterization), which says:

> If you’d like to find more queries that sp_BlitzCache didn’t report as performance problems, this query will list all of them in the cache:

Run that query and bask in the warm knowledge that comes with reading - not just clicking on - the documentation. ;-)